# Mean-value theorem for function that is non-differentiable at a point

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Let us a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which is continuous but not differentiable at $0$.

In particular, I want to focus on $$\tilde f:x\mapsto |x|^{-1/2}x$$
**Question:** Is it true that the mean-value theorem holds for $\tilde f$? That is, for every $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R$, there exists $\bar x \in \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ such that $$\tilde f'(\bar x) = \frac{\tilde f(x_1)-\tilde f(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}$$
holds?

If yes, as an additional question, I'd like to ask how can a more general mean-value theorem be stated without differentiability assumption (or replacing differentiability by something else).

Comment: How would you talk about the derivative of $f$ without requiring differentiability?

Comment: @Lorago Maybe similarly as my example, assuming that the function is differentiable at all except a finite number of points?

Comment: Seems relevant: Dwight Benjamin Goodner, [*Mean value theorems for functions with finite derivates*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2309443), **American Mathematical Monthly** 67 #9 (November 1960), pp. 852-855. First 3 sentences: *The law of the mean and many of its extensions require the existence of the derivative. However, since the derivative may fail to exist, it seems desirable to have expressions which may serve us when there is no derivative. The purpose of this paper is to consider extensions of the law of the mean to functions which have finite right and left “Dini derivates.”*

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. If you look at $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$, then, for each $x\neq 0$,
$$\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2x} = 0$$
but the tangent to $f$ is nowhere horizontal.

Comment: The OP's question is not in general, but in particular for his function $\tilde{f}$.

Comment: @uniquesolution in his last senctence the OP asks for a a general version. Also, the example shows that there is no general theorem which would allow to conclude such a statement for the function the OP is looking at. Also the OPs answer to a question in the comments shows that my example may be useful

Comment: Thanks. What about the situation with $\tilde f$ though?